# SSH Public key denied on "git clone" command

Tags: git, ssh, github, heroku, ssh-keys

I am trying to clone a git repo that I forked in my GitHub Repository.It's a rails app. I want to clone it on my local git so that I can push it onto heroku. I generated a set of rsa keys and copied it onto my GitHUb public keys. When I try to `git clone "public url"` , It says public key denied. I tried an `ssh git@github.com` to verify my key, it also says public key denied. I've tried several different things to make it work but it still hasn't. I tried to change permissions to 600 and 700 on my .ssh folder. I also tried adding a dsa key because the rsa won't work. please help me. Thanks. :)

I'm on Vista btw.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Answering a very old thread, here, but I'm on Cygwin and just had to do this to start work with my newly created site on [phpfog.com](http://phpfog.com)

First, I ran this in cygwin:

```
exec ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/private-key-name
```

I then received:

```
Identity added: /home/scott/.ssh/private-key-name (/home/scott/.ssh/private-key-name)
```

Comment: This fixed some very annoying `git clone` issues for me.  Why must SSH/SSL identity management be so perpetually obtuse?

Comment: For me it adds identity only for the started bash window (I am on Cygwin) but after I close it command-line commands continue rejecting the public key. Any chance to make this change permanent?

Comment: This fixed my `git push origin master` issue with Springloops. Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Copy the public key on your computer i.e., `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (open it with notepad)

Paste this key in the "Add SSH key" section in your github account.

Note: to generate a ssh key if doesnt already exist, use `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Answer (score 3):

Can you try adding the private key using `ssh-add`?

Comment: I tried it and it said 
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: eval $(ssh-agent) cannot resolve any issue beacuse if agent is not runnin then Agent pid will be random number

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of googling, I found [this answer](http://www.trycatchfail.com/blog/post/2009/11/24/Fun-with-Git-how-to-re-attach-your-ssh-key-on-a-new-machine.aspx). I had to start the bash engine before i can add the keys. I cloned my app from github to my local server as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, you can try [keychain](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/keychain) tool to manage SSH agent.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using ForwardAgent option.

Try add:

```
Host * 
    ForwardAgent yes
```

to /etc/ssh/ssh_config on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
Check the contents of your public key file:

1. it must start with ssh-rsa
2. it must be ONE line
3. the format is like this:
   ssh-rsa manysymbolshere== somekeyname

if you generated the key using puttygen in Windows - DO NOT save public key to a file on disk - it will have comments, which you must delete before copying to a server.
Copy the public key to clipboard and then save to a *.pub file using notepad.

Answer (score -1):

[SSL certificate rejected trying to access GitHub over HTTPS behind firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777075/https-github-access) looks to be a very similar question.  One solution I took from [from those answers](https://nsidc.org/mailman/listinfo/icebridgeportal) to quickly clone a git repository when I don't have the keys set up is to:

```
export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true
```

then clone away.