# SSL certificate issue when trying to clone Git repository within Cygwin

Tags: git, ssl, https, cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTPS github access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777075/https-github-access)

I am trying to clone a Git repository from Cygwin running on Windows 7. I am entering the command `git clone http://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat` and getting this result:

```
Cloning into node-chat...
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify
    failed while accessing https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

It seems like I get some sort of error whenever I try to do anything involving an https URL in Cygwin. How can I make the clone work?

Comment: I installed the root certificates as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777075/https-github-access/4454754#4454754 and now I am no longer getting this error. Feel free to mark this question as a duplicate.