# Unable to clone repo in bluemix dedicated. Bad certificate chain

Tags: github, ibm-cloud

I am unable to clone a repository hosted on the github enterprise for Bluemix Dedicated. I am getting the following error:

> abort: error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
>   failed (_ssl.c:590) fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.w3ibm.bluemix.net/scottchapman/ESSToscanaActionTraining/':
>   SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git SSL certificate- Invalid certificate chain while accessing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331325/git-ssl-certificate-invalid-certificate-chain-while-accessing)

Comment: That work-around worked...