# Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm getting this error when trying to run rspec in Hartl's tutorial. I googled the error, but it's never for the specific version and the fixes don't actually fix my problem.

```
/Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `require': dlopen(/Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-           1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): Library not loaded:    /Users/Jimbo/.bundler/tmp/22862/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/i686-apple-   darwin11/libxml2/2.8.0/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-  1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
Reason: Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0 - /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
from /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /Users/Jimbo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
```

Comment: I am gettting same kind of error: LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/2.3/nokogiri

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I suggest you first uninstall Nokogiri using:

```
sudo gem uninstall nokogiri
```

Then install Nokogiri using rubygems:

```
gem install nokogiri
```

If that doesn't work, there's an [open issue](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/986) on Nokogiri to support libxml 2.9.0 and later. There's a [libxml2-2.9.1 branch](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/tree/libxml2-2.9.1) that was started in preparation for the next release of libxml2.

Then try pulling from that branch in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem "nokogiri", github: "sparklemotion/nokogiri", branch: "libxml2-2.9.1"
```

or install an older version of libxml2.

If that still doesn't work you may also want to try the suggestions here: [What to do if libxml2 is being a jerk.](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/What-to-do-if-libxml2-is-being-a-jerk)

Comment: That branch doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if it helps anyone, but I could just get nokogiri installed by using system libs

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

Comment: nothing above helped, this thing made it work like charm! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you have Homebrew installed, try this. It solves the issue with the "Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.6.1" hang. This worked for me.

```
gem uninstall nokogiri libxml-ruby
```

It'll ask you a series of questions based on how much of it you want to uninstall, answer "yes" or "[y]" to all.

```
brew update
brew uninstall libxml2
brew install libxml2 --with-xml2-config
brew link --force libxml2
brew install libxslt 
brew link --force libxslt 

gem install nokogiri --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Then, in your project file:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error message says:

> nokogiri.bundle requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib
>   provides version 10.0.0

This makes me think that your gem actually requires a version of libxml that is *newer* than your system version. How have you installed libxml2? If you have homebrew installed, you might want to try upgrading it with

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

I was able to install Nokogiri 1.6.0 with Ruby 2.0.0p247 on OS X 10.9, and then require it in IRb. I double checked with Homebrew, and it is actually [keg-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691403/keg-only-homebrew-formulas). However, Nokogiri seems to install its own version into `gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports`. On my machine, it is under x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0.

Comment: Thanks, @Shepmaster. Ryan's answer worked for me (uninstalling and reinstalling nokogiri).

Answer (score 1):

First `gem uninstall nokogiri`
Second `install nokogiri`
third restart terminal

be happy

Answer (score 1):

Try the following inside your project directory.

```
gem uninstall nokogiri
```

If there are more than one versions installed, a prompt will appear asking which version to remove. use the last option that reads "All versions".

Next, run `bundle install` inside your project directory. once it finishes installing the needed gems you should be good to go.

In my case, I hit the last option "All versions" as it doesn't hurt my project but it is possible that you might need the other versions based on different projects.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the gem didn't work for me, nor did pulling the particular branch.

It's not ideal, but I found that rolling back to 1.5.9 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your version of libxml:

```
otool -L /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
```

It can return

```
/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
```

or

```
/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.9.0)
```

Then you can try reinstalling libxml to upgrade it:

```
brew uninstall libxml2 libxslt
brew install libxml2 libxslt
```

After that, try to recompile your package:

```
make clean
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri generally uses system libraries. So, your ruby has it installed already just make sure that you've run below command before start **bundle install**.

> rvm use ruby-2.2.4 (your current ruby-version)

Sometimes, you also need to run first

> 1. /bin/bash --login
> 2. rvm use ruby-2.2.4

**Note:** Only if you're using **rvm**