# Nokogiri won't load in production through Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano, nokogiri, bundler

I'm running Ruby 2.2.3p173 on Ubuntu 15.10 with Capistrano for deployment. Deployment went off without a problem and bundled successfully but if I try to open the rails console, I get this with no additional information outside of the backtrace:

**Error:**

```
/home/anthony/apps/portal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in 'require': incompatible library version -` 
/home/anthony/apps/portal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so (LoadError)`
```

If I open irb, I can `require 'nokogiri'` and it works fine, but when I use bundler with `Bundler.require`, I get the same error.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling nokogiri and updating to the newest version. Also went through the advice in the official tutorial [here](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#ubuntu___debian).

Comment: have you read this? http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#ubuntu___debian

Comment: How is your question different from http://stackoverflow.com/q/18818926/128421 ?

Comment: @Anthony, yes I tried the nokogiri tutorial which didn't make a difference.

Comment: @theTinMan,  I don't get a reason along with the error.

Comment: When asking a question like this, you need to tell us what you tried to fix the problem, and what the results were of each step. As is, you're asking us to iterate through all possible things to try, wait for you to do them or tell us you already tried that. That's a waste of our time. We need more information to provide a detailed answer.