# require': incompatible library version - /home/suresh/.gem/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While running the server, i am getting the error incompatible library version.Already Nokogiri is installed in my system.Any Advice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20006530/5934752

Answer (score 0):

I would reinstall rvm or rbenv. Also try:

```
$gem uninstall nokogiri libxml-ruby
$brew update
$brew uninstall libxml2
$brew install libxml2 --with-xml2-config
$brew link --force libxml2
$brew install libxslt
$brew link --force libxslt

$bundle config build.nokogiri -- --with-xml2-dir=/usr --with-xslt-    dir=/opt/local --with-iconv-dir=/opt/local
$bundle install
```

I had a similiar issue when upgrading to rails 5. This worked for me.