# LoadError: incompatible library version - nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am facing below error when I tried to

`run rake db:migrate`

Log:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-3.2.2/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:2:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-3.2.2/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-3.2.2/lib/roadie.rb:29:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-3.2.2/lib/roadie.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-rails-1.2.1/lib/roadie/rails.rb:6:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-rails-1.2.1/lib/roadie/rails.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-rails-1.2.1/lib/roadie-rails.rb:1:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-rails-1.2.1/lib/roadie-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/fs_finance/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/fs_finance/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/2.3/nokogiri
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:30:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.8.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-3.2.2/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:2:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-3.2.2/lib/roadie/inliner.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-3.2.2/lib/roadie.rb:29:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-3.2.2/lib/roadie.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-rails-1.2.1/lib/roadie/rails.rb:6:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-rails-1.2.1/lib/roadie/rails.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-rails-1.2.1/lib/roadie-rails.rb:1:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/roadie-rails-1.2.1/lib/roadie-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/fs_finance/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/fs_finance/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: try uninstall and install nokogiri gem. I think, related one https://stackoverflow.com/a/20006530/5076451

Answer (score 6):

Please check your gem version and run

`gem pristine --all`

Comment: Thanks Sonu. It helped me to solve my problem. 
Can you explain a bit more how this can help?

Comment: For me, I believe this happened when I switched from `chruby` to `rbenv` and I suspect this somehow made built native extensions invalid. `gem pristine --all` essentially reinstalls all the gems (and their native extensions). I suspect that it would have been faster and just as effective to do `gem pristine --extensions`