# Rails install fail by permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

## nokogiri install failure

### What I want

Install ruby on rails

#### error

Gemfile is done, and I want to install rails.
Obaying the document, `bundle install --path=vendor/bundle`
but 
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.10.3), 
and Bundler cannot continue. The error is here.

```
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.3'
--source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

answer

I searched google for the error message, then find
[incompatible-library-version]
([Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818926/incompatible-library-version-nokogiri-bundle-requires-version-11-0-0-or-later))

```
 sudo gem uninstall nokogiri
 gem uninstall nokogiri
```

sudo gem uninstall nokogiri
I obaied the command but it cause new error:

```
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.3/LICENSE-DEPENDENCIES.md
```

There 1614 lines dependencies document, 
but I cannot find out what to do next.

Please help me (><)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/ruby
```

And bundle install again or gem install again and netter not use sudo on gem install