# Git clone on Mac with HTTPS not working

Tags: git, macos

I use Git in Windows and Linux on a daily basis and I was just trying to get it going on my Mac but am having an issue doing a simple `git clone`. I used the installer from the Git website as well as the bash script which adds the environment variable in `~/.MacOSX`

I say that because I'm not completely sure everything is setup correctly, I also have the ssh key added to my github account.

So heres the full output from the terminal

```
myComp:Sites me$ git clone https://github.com/me/some_project.git
Cloning into some_project...
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/me/some_project.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
myComp:Sites me$
```

Here is what the environment.plist looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTPS github access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777075/https-github-access)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what worked for me and it may or may not be the best solution but its certainly the easiest.

`git config --global --add http.sslVerify false`

Comment: To keep ssl enabled for curl, the following might help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15668566/389103.

Comment: God, please do _not_ do this. Disabling SSL verification is an unwise solution to any problem, it completely defeats all the protections that SSL provides for identifying trusted servers. Fix it correctly, fix your trusted root certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I researched your problem a bit and found someone that had a similar issue. Apparently what the issue was for them was that they had a duplicate environment variable in their path. Are you positive that git has not already been installed on this machine before? Could you take a look at your ~/.MacOSX file and see if there is anything fishy going on in it?

Comment: I couldnt tell you how fishy it looks but I posted an edit.  I went ahead and followed an example on Github but no luck.