# SSL error while trying to push to github

Tags: git, github, git-push

This is a REPO I just created (my first one) so I might have set it up wrongly.
When I try to PUSH the code from my machine to the REPO on GIT, I get:

> error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
>   verify failed while accessing
>   https://github.com/itay-moav/OmegaSupreme.git/info/refs

What am I doing wrong, am I missing a setup step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad solution would be:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

The right solution would be to [add the root certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454754/6309) (you can [see an example here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/6103#issuecomment-1417990)).
That being said, using a Git distribution like [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.com/) on Windows, or [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) (or [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/)) would avoid that, since it would use cert file with the right certificates already installed.
Msysgit, for instance, references its own - complete - `bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt` file, with the right CAs already in it. See "[Unable to access github via `curl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257834/6309)".