# Fatal error on git push origin master?

Tags: git, github

I did push origin master and after that I have an error:

> $ git push origin master
>
> fatal:
>   https://github.com/myusername/my-first-project-test.git/info/refs not
>   found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

I did:

> $ git update-server-info

but it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Clicking that link leads to "Repository not found."  Are you sure this is a valid repository?

Comment: i.e. have you created that repository on github yet?

Comment: I'm very sure, and it's must be Rep Not Found, caz I wrote an example (not real nickname and repo).

Comment: My Real Repo and Nickname returns me this fatal error. If it's so means I can post real data, but there is only a 1 single file called README. With Hello, World!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be an authorization problem.

I would suggest you try to use the ssh protocol rather than https:

```
git@github.com:<user>/<reponame>.git
```

([source](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/issues/87))

Also, make sure that in your global `.gitconfig` you have

```
[http]
      sslVerify = true
```

You can fix that from the command line by issuing

```
git config --global http.sslVerify true
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777075/https-github-access))

Comment: yes. Thank you Geretti it was auth problem really. Can't vote know.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Was there something more specific you had to do to solve your problem? If you post it here as a comment, it can provide a more accurate solution to the future reader.

Comment: Sure, I had a second account for github, that I've created long time ago, and forgot about him, so thats why was a confuse between old and new .ssh keys. So I did new .ssh key to resolve a conflict, but seems another 1 issue, what if I want to use both account?

Comment: Never tried that actually, be there are some questions in SO related to your problem: [GitHub two accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=github+two+accounts)