# Git push to remote repository gives fatal error SSH HTTPS

Tags: git, github

I am developing an ionic app,and I use **Git** as my version control method.My remote repository is located in GitHub.Whenever I am trying to *push* some content from my local repository to remote repository,Git will give this Fatal Error,

```
fatal: remote error:
  You can't push to git://github.com/evilmin/ionicMyApp.git
  Use https://github.com/evilmin/ionicMyApp.git
```

I checked the remote links using the command `git remote -v` and it gave me this output.

```
origin  git://github.com/evilmin/ionicMyApp.git (fetch)
origin  git://github.com/evilmin/ionicMyApp.git (push)
```

Means the error was right and the links are in SSH.
So I tried removing the origin and add it as a HTTPS link using

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/evilmin/ionicMyApp.git
```

But when I run the `git remote -v` to check the remotes,I get the same output that I have mentioned above,which means the links are still in SSH,and my command has not worked. 
And yes I tried pushing again,but the same error occurs.
I even tried *reinstalling Git*,but the issue persists.
Whatever the repository is,every time I try to push from a local repo to its  remote repo,it will give me this error.
My main concern is how to *enable push functionality again* in Git.Any ideas would be helpful. 
It would be better if there is a way to do this using HTTPS,rather than SSH.

P.S. : This happened not only when I was developing an Ionic app,but also other times,hence I believe Ionic was not the reason.

Comment: git:// is *not* ssh though.

Comment: See Luca Geretti's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018358/fatal-error-on-git-push-origin-master .He refers git:// as ssh,right?

Comment: No he does not. He is using `git@`, not `git://`

Comment: My bad,then.Thanks for the clarification.What I experienced was ' git:// '.I thought it meant SSH.Anyway I need a solution where I can go push to remote repo without any issues.(Better if it's via HTTPS).

Comment: git:// is the git protocol: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_git_protocol

Answer (score 4):

Why do not you git clone remote repo to https ?

First delete the local project before git clone

if you want ssh

first remove .ssh know host github url

and Re-register the public key.

Comment: I suppose that you suggest to clone my repo.I dit it in both ways.1)Downloaded it as a zip and opened Git Bash inside that. 2)Opened GIt Bash in a certain directory and run 'git clone <remote repo url>' code . None of those solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting SSH method :) ,but I'd be more grateful if there is a way to use HTTPS because it is simpler. I have edited my question.

Comment: i can not find you ionic repo. check remote repo is private or public

if the repo is a private you can't access or wrong credentials.

Instead of

git clone https://github.com/NAME/repo.git
url should be

git clone https://username:password@github.com/NAME/repo.git

Comment: It is because I have replaced my actual account name.Sorry about that.And it definitely is a public repository.And this does not happen for a certain repository.I tried that with several repos. And I did it using another computer as well.