# How do I get Leopard to work with ssl from the command line

Tags: macos, git, curl, darwin

Everything I try and connect to via https fails. Bellow is a curl output, but it does this with git mongo and everything. darwin just doesn't like https.

- About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
- Trying 207.97.227.239... connected
- Connected to github.com (207.97.227.239) port 443 (#0)
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: /usr/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
- SSLv2, Client hello (1):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
- SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
- SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
- Closing connection #0
  curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

You might say not a problem just change https to http, yes this is fine when you only have 
1 url like git clone but on rvm install about 50 of the required things fails to install because of this. I don't want to go into rvm and change all occurrences of https to http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my version of curl was using an old certificate to validate https.

I cam across this issue on git for cURL under Leopard:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11947

And the error went away and I am now able to download https files from cURL.

Comment: Err... that sounds pretty much like the "outdated CA file" issue I referred you to. What was the solution for git?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post, slightly different, but i think it will answer you questions:

[SSL certificate rejected trying to access GitHub over HTTPS behind firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777075/https-github-access)

You can essentially have OSX ignore the SSL Cert Verify, and accept the connection.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like an issue with curl itself, rather than OSX. What version are you using? If it's particularly old, then the reference here to a ["severely outdated CA file"](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) probably applies.

Try installing up-to-date versions of curl and git from macports.

Comment: Its the same with git too, and I am running the latest version of CURL (compiled from source), and on the compilation it said

https ready no

Comment: More like the CA file it uses.  See http://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2011/06/github_ssl_ca_errors.html