# git ssl without env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true

Tags: git, netbeans, ssl

İ install my own git server in distant machine with ssl.

whene i use this command:

env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/git/project.git

all is fine, and with env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true all git command work fine.

but i need pull and push with netbeans ide, so with netbeans ide i connot add this

> env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true

so netbeans say:

> Cannot connect to the remote repository at https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/git/project.git

What i need to do?

Answer (score 33):

You could do this (from the [`git-config`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) manual page):

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

But what's the point of having it on an https server if the certificate won't properly validate?

Comment: İ try this but netbeans always the same he can't pull or fetch repos

Comment: One good reason for using this option is to use it as a workaround, while the server admin fixes the server certificate :D

Comment: Or, for smaller devs who run simple server setups behind a VPN, a signed cert is overkill.

Comment: @Chase, why wouldn't you just use HTTP then? Security by obscurity because you don't want casual observers to know the URLs of your repositories? (If they knew nobody was checking the certificate, they could just launch a MitM attack to find out that info.)

Comment: actually, I'm using SSL on my GitBlit installation because I couldn't run it directly in IIS, and therefore can't use port 80 with a host name the way I wanted to. Running it on port 443 was just easier and quicker to get up and running.

Comment: @Chase, I see. I guess you might want to consider configuring that self-signed certificate as trusted, or bring up your own internal CA. I'm not familiar with IIS, but you might consider using a port that's not 80, another hostname, or a reverse-proxy setup. I'd hate to incur extra HTTPS overhead downloading a large repository if you don't need it.

Comment: If i set http.sslVerify false then connection will secure? and it is good path to use ? In between we are using pfsense firewall

Comment: @user1261959, no, any time you bypass SSL certificate checks, you will be vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. To make it secure, you'll need a PKI infrastructure, and you'll need to issue a signed certificate to the git server, and ensure the client trusts the CA who issued that certificate.

Comment: @Mike We are using on gateway as a pfsense firewall and with squid+https enable; then is it secure connection, I think

Comment: @user1261959 buzzwords aside (pfsense and squid really aren't really relevant here), it really depends on your threat model. But anyone with access to your network and the skills and motivation could intercept *or change* the traffic between your git server and whoever is pulling/pushing from it in this way. Think about it; they could send traffic to their own server and deliver a certificate signed by whoever they want, and the client would trust it! Then they could talk to the *real* server themselves on your behalf, and you might not even detect the intrusion.

Answer (score 7):

If the https server uses a self-signed certificate, save it to your local machine's hard disk (in `.crt` format), and add this to `.git/config` for the relevant working copy

```
[http]
        sslCAInfo=/path/to/your-server-certificate.crt
```

That will make it always expect that certificate when connecting to the https server in question, and not otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I like this solution better since it doesn't subvert the *entire* purpose of https. The whole concept of `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` just seems wrong. You might as well just put your source code on a plain `http://` server if you aren't going to validate the certificate.

Comment: İ was generate my certificate in the server like this:
openssl req $@ -new -x509 -days 1460 -nodes -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

i copy / paste /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem in this file:
/home/www/mycert.crt

in my local repos i try to add this:

[http]
 sslCAInfo=/home/www/mycert.crt

But with netbeans i can't pull or fetch repos :(

Comment: I don't know for sure that this is your problem, but, PEM and CRT are different formats, and I think Git insists on CRT.  You can convert it like so: `openssl x509 -in /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem -inform PEM -out /home/www/mycert.crt -outform DER`.  (Do that *instead of* copying the file over.)  Then test it by doing `git fetch` from the command line in the repo that you want to use Netbeans with.  If that works and netbeans still doesn't, I am out of ideas.

Comment: If i set http.sslVerify false then connection will secure? and it is good path to use ? In between we are using pfsense firewall

Comment: @user1261959 No and no.  Do not do that.

Comment: @user1261959 I am unfamiliar with pfsense, but to first order, the _only_ thing a firewall should do is restrict external access to a whitelist of hosts and TCP ports (e.g. "allow ports 80 and 443 to www.yourcompany.com but not elsewhere"). Enabling additional features (such as packet inspection of any kind) is likely to make you _less_ secure.

Comment: @user1261959 Ask for more help on serverfault.com or security.stackexchange.com; the comments are not for discussion of related problems.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with other posters that GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY or other means of preventing certificate verification is not the right solution.  The best solution only takes a few seconds to implement, and is found in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8467406/994153
It involves downloading the certificate `.pem` file and setting the Git configuration variable `http.sslCAinfo` to point to the file.

Comment: If i set http.sslVerify false then connection will secure? and it is good path to use ? In between we are using pfsense firewall

Comment: If you set sslVerify to false, then the connection is insecure, losing all guarantee of confidentiality and integrity.