# Github clone issue

Tags: powershell, github

I am trying to clone a git project known as Storm-Starter however I am getting the following error when running the `git clone https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter.git` command:

```
Cloning into 'storm-starter'...
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/nat
hanmarz/storm-starter.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I have followed the tutorial on github (as somebody suggested to doing so when such an issue occurs) on how to [generate and submit the SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) and everything went well,so I have no idea what is happening.

I am also running this on Windows 8 machine.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: Oh,not really,could it be the issue that I am using my android phone usb internet tethering to gain access to the internet?

Comment: You may find more information here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8755199/1706698

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the SSL CERT verification by setting:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

See [here](http://whatiscomingtomyhead.wordpress.com/2013/06/06/problems-cloning-git-repository-over-https/).