# EGIT saying Read timed out after 30,000 ms

Tags: git, egit

Im trying to clone a remote repo over http in my local dest.
im using egit on eclipse luna.

but im always getting error read timed out after 30,000ms.

i know http is correct protocol for it, my username passsword is correct but still this problem occuring multiple times.

pls see screenshot for more clear idea.
[image]

UPDDATE: 11-5-2014
When i saw eclipse error log at location *.metadata/log*
I saw following error message..... i think it says same.... but still adding here in case if it can help solving this problem....
error message is

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 4 0 2014-11-05 19:09:13.827
!MESSAGE Read timed out after 30,000 ms
!STACK 0

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: Read timed out after 30,000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CloneOperation.run(CloneOperation.java:156)
    at 

org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.executeCloneOperation(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.access$2(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard$6.run(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Read timed out after 30,000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$SmartHttpFetchConnection.doFetch(TransportHttp.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.fetchObjects(FetchProcess.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Read timed out after 30,000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.readTimedOut(TimeoutInputStream.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.read(TimeoutInputStream.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.IO.readFully(IO.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readLength(PacketLineIn.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readString(PacketLineIn.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readACK(PacketLineIn.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.negotiate(BasePackFetchConnection.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:356)
    ... 15 more
```

can anybody help me to resolve this prob?
thanks in advance !!

Comment: This might be solved by [disabling SSL Verification](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21909036/3991344).

Comment: @Pokechu22 I'm dubious, given that his repository isn't being accessed via https.  It could be redirecting to https, though.

Comment: Have you tried to clone the repository using a different git client?  That would at least narrow down whether it's an EGit issue or a problem with your remote repository.

Comment: @ZoogieZork i am new to git thing and know only abt egit plugin for eclipse. I use windows. I am doubtful if thiis is error with remote repo as my team mates can access it using same eclipse luna and egit on their respective laptops.

Comment: Take a look at [GitEye](http://www.collab.net/giteyeapp) for Windows to test cloning with.  If you're unable to clone with GitEye, then it might be some network, firewall, or proxy issue with your system, in which case you should take your question to [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: I had this same problem. I used TortoiseGit to solve it.

Answer (score 42):

I had similar problem with huge repository. The solution was a quick change of settings:

> Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Remote connections

where "Remote connection timeout (sec)" was set to 30[s]. (30000ms). Set it higher.

Answer (score 7):

go to the option window -> preferences-> java 
expand java and search debug
in debug change the debugger timeout for 30000.

Try again to clone and that is all.

Answer (score 3):

You can change connection timeout from eclipse.

GO TO

> Windows >> Preferences >> Git

and then the change connection timeout value to higher.

See below screenshot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[EGit-ConfigureFetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyzFt.jpg)Tried the following in Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 with positive results:

1. Right click on your Remote Repository.
2. Select Configure Fetch...
3. Remove the default Ref mapping and click on Advanced.
4. Select the specific branch that you want to checkout and Click on Add Spec.
5. Check/Uncheck Force Update checkbox depending on your preference.
6. Select the radio button Never fetch Tags.
7. Save your Fetch Configuration and try again.