# Does buildout/easy_install/setup_tools verify SSL certificates?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, easy-install, buildout, sni

I'm trying to diagnose this error:

```
Getting distribution for 'zc.buildout<2dev'.
Got zc.buildout 1.7.1.
Generated script '/opt/mytardis/releases/a549cd05272afe8f16c2fe5efe8158490acbde82/bin/buildout'.
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/buildout-versions/: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'buildout-versions' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer -- Some packages may not be found!
Getting distribution for 'buildout-versions'.
STDERR: /usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'src_root'
  warnings.warn(msg)
While:
  Installing.
  Loading extensions.
  Getting distribution for 'buildout-versions'.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'buildout-versions'.
```

It happens deep inside a Chef + buildout installation stack. One thing I have discovered is that if I attempt to access the buildout-versions package directly:

```
$ wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/buildout-versions/buildout-versions-1.7.tar.gz#md5=731ecc0c9029f45826fa9f31d44e311d
--2013-07-09 12:50:18--  https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/buildout-versions/buildout-versions-1.7.tar.gz
Resolving proxy.redacted.com... 123.45.67.8
Connecting to proxy.redacted.com|123.45.67.8|:8080... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name “*.a.ssl.fastly.net” doesn’t match requested host name “pypi.python.org”.
To connect to pypi.python.org insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.
```

I can access the file fine from my desktop. So I suspect the proxy (provided by a university, and this server has to use it to reach the web). It's set with `https_proxy=...`.

Is this the likely cause of buildout failing? Any way around it?

Comment: Can you access `http://pypi.python.org/simple/buildout-versions`? The buildout you use does *not* try to use HTTPS at all.

Comment: Hmm, this is getting complicated. Going to that site in a browser redirects to https:// . Going there in Lynx from the site gives SSL warnings. And most confusingly, wget on a different server using the same proxy works just fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your version of wget is too old.

wget started to support SNI ([Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)) only since version 1.14 and that TLS extension is needed to be presented the correct certificate on pypi.python.org.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `zc.buildout` and `easy_install` both use `urllib2` to retrieve HTTPS resources, [which does *not* verify SSL certificates](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> **Warning**: HTTPS requests do not do any verification of the server’s certificate.

Your `wget` tool does verify certificates, but your local certificate authorities certificates are incomplete, it seems; see [SSL certificate rejected trying to access GitHub over HTTPS behind firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777075/ssl-certificate-rejected-trying-to-access-github-over-https-behind-firewall) for instructions on how to update those.

As for your original error, it appears your firewall proxy is doing the peer resets.

As per [PEP 476](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/), Python 2.7.9 remedies this situation. From that version onwards, `urllib2` will verify SSL certificates by default.

Comment: Which bit in particular is the "instructions on how to update those"? Tried `yum update openssl` and `yum install ca-certificates` (probably the wrong package name) but no good.

Comment: Pip does no longer use urllib2; it uses Requests now.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: Ah, indeed, from 1.5 onwards in a change made in August 2013 I see. I removed `pip` from the list.

Comment: Situation changes with 2.7.9/3.4.3, which by default perform a verification.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: thanks for the heads-up; I was just dealing with some [fallout from that change](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2395), but I didn't realise I had answers on SO to update.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for updating. And, yes, this unfortunately is not the only system affected by the SSL refactoring in 2.7.9: https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/477 - http://bugs.python.org/issue22438 - https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2901

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 2.7.9 (released) / 3.4.3 (released soon), certificates are validated by default:

> HTTPS certificate validation using the system's certificate store is
>   now enabled by default. See PEP 476 for details.

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/

Answer (score 0):

you can try it:

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg#md5=fe1f997bc722265116870bc7919059ea --no-check-certificate
```

Comment: Seriously, telling people not to check certificates is bordering on the criminal...

Comment: @BrunoRohée Hopefully authors of wget and other net tools do not agree with you :)

Comment: There's a difference between selling a gun and telling someone to commit suicide, offering a --no-check-certificate is like selling a gun, telling someone to use it downloading a package from the great Internet is more akin to tell him to play russian roulette...

Comment: instead of ignoring ssl errors, just use openssl(1) to get a copy of the certificate and add that to your CA store (ie /etc/pki/..,/etc/ssl/..)