# Failure connecting to ldap server from clearcase dir

Tags: .net, windows-7, ldap, clearcase

We migrated from Windows XP to 7, and we're currently using clearcase as our version control.

I have a .NET app that worked perfectly fine on XP, and works fine if I run it from my local drive.
But when I run it from its clearcase directory, for some reason its gets denied a request for a LdapConnection.

Can it be some weird win7 privilages thing?
Or is it clearcase related?

It cant be the app as it works fine in every other condition.

Thanks in advace, Avi.

EDIT:
I feel like I haven't supplied enough details, so here they are:
I'm using a 64 bit version of WIN7, and working on a dynamic view of clearcase version 7.1

The point of failure is a c# code line that initiates a new instnace of LdapConnection class.
I'm getting an LdapException saying "The connection cannot be established"

Its not a server issue as the exact same code works fine when run from WIN XP or WIN7 on a local C: drive.

Comment: Is that clearcase directory a dynamic view on the network?

Comment: Yes, its a dynamic view

Comment: This one maybe: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405894

Answer (score 1):

ClearCase in itself shouldn't be concerned with LDAP, not directly at least, considering [its level of integration with LDAP](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21117293):

> When LDAP authentication is enabled, users enter names and passwords through standard ClearCase dialogs (for example CCRC or CCWeb), and ClearCase will use the LDAP protocol to deliver the appropriate authentication.
>
> This is not to say that ClearCase is integrated with LDAP, it merely runs on top of the operating system already configured to use the LDAP protocol. In other words, ClearCase authenticates with the operating system, and will support LDAP transparently if the OS is configured correctly to support LDAP.

Note that may have changed with ClearTeam Explorer and CC 8.x

So if you weren't using LDAP before the migration for authentication, check if there is any trigger in place which, in the new environment (Win7 client) could mis-behave.
If not, check the ClearCase logs (both clients and server), especially if you are running the program from a dynamic view.

One workaround would be to run the same program from a snapshot view.

Comment: What clearcsse dialogs? There is c# code that connects to ldap which fails only when running from my dynamic view in my 64 bit win7... Nothing else was changed.

Comment: @AviSasson so your LDAP integration isn't with ClearCase? It is a feature of your app, which doesn't work anymore in a ClearCase dynamic view under W7, correct? What version of ClearCase are you using?

Comment: @AviSasson is it possible that you don't have the right to write within your dynamic view? (I assume it is the same than the one you were using on WXp) Do you have set `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` (like you had in your previous environment)

Comment: I don't think that's the issue because I had to compile about 20 solutions on this view before running the app and there was not problem with the compilation.
Furthermore, when the app starts running it unzips an oracle client zip file to the directory it runs from (which is on that same view) and that operation runs succefully, so it cant be a write permisssions issue.

BTW, I updated the original post with all the details I missed, maybe the extra details can shed some more light on the matter.

Comment: About the group thing - I checked an XP computer, not PRIMARY_GROUP defined so I guess there's no need to define one.

Comment: @AviSasson can you compare the output of `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro yourDynamicView`, both in Xp and Win7? Is there anything in the ClearCase logs, both on the client side and server side?

Comment: I'm doing the lsview thing now, but where do I see the logs? Expacially the server logs?
I found some clearcase log viewer, but I already tried that and there's nothing new there after the app crashes.

Comment: @AviSasson type `clearhomebase`, and click on Log Browser: by default it displays the log of your computer. You can open a new log browser, inputing the name of your ClearCase server.

Comment: Couldn't find anything in log.
About the lsview thing - I did the comparing, but what am I looking for?
The only differences there are names, timestamps and something called AdditionalGroups which lists all kinds of domain groups.

Comment: @AviSasson I would still recommend setting the `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` to the same group than the primary group listed in a `cleartool descr -l vob:\vobYouNeedToAccess`

Comment: @AviSasson beside that, it could be a good case to submit to IBM support. Were you on WXp 32 bits or 64 bits before?

Comment: I was on 32 bit
Set the primary group to the same group as the one returned by the script?
And what vob object?

Comment: @AviSasson when you are launching your app, you must be in a path like `m:\myDynamicView\myVob\apath`: the first directory after `m:\myDynamicView` is a vob name.

Comment: @AviSasson ok, just checking here. There seems to be a writing access issue, which is why I recommended setting this.

Comment: Any other ideas?
It's either that or I revert to WinXP and I really like 7 :(

Comment: @AviSasson no direct clue right now. I would suggest open a case to IBM support and/or debugging your C# app, to pinpoint the exact command which triggers the error.

Comment: I did the debug, its a line initializg a new instance of LdapConnection class.
The parameters passed are fine since they work when run from C

Comment: @AviSasson also, make sure your environment variables are the same. If, for instance, you have `HTTP(S)_PROXY` vars on Win7, and not on WinXp, that could explain a connection issue.

Comment: What is this variable about?
Is it a user or a system variable?

Comment: @AviSasson It is for program making internet connections: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18458500/6309 (user environment variables, not system)

Comment: I don't quite follow what the HttpProxy var has to do with my problem.
I'm not connected to the WWW, its an internal network and I'm trying to connect to one of our own servers. Besides, if I were blocked wouldn't the app get blocked when run from C drive also?

Comment: @AviSasson true, this seems more related to the MVFS (the file system behind dynamic view) on Win7. I never saw an LDAP error on it though.

Comment: Supposed it is MVFS related, how would you go about diagnosing the problem?

Comment: @AviSasson if it is really related to MVFS, then something should pop up in the logs (of the ClearCase client, or of the ClearCase server). If not, I would open a PMR to IBM support.