# what does this error message imply: fatal: unable to access 'https:URL': Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized?

Tags: git, ssl, certificate

I have tried many different searches relating to certificates but I don't get it. I don't know how to see if I have good certificates or not. This message was given after trying to push a a git commit in Fedora like this:

```
$ git push origin master
```

Is this certificate related or git related? btw ssh works...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One possibility would be the absence of Certification Authority certificates on your system.

If that is the case, you can add those as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454754/6309).

This is better than ignoring said CA (`env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://github...`).

---

In the specific case for this OP, [Brandon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1965708/brandon-dewey) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461833/what-does-this-error-message-imply-fatal-unable-to-access-httpsurl-peers/19464361#comment28968730_19464361):

> I am running 64 bit fedora 19 and, as `root`, I went to `/etc/ssl/certs` and saw there was a makefile, so I ran it with a different serial i.e.:

```
$ make SERIAL=5
```

> Tried `git` and it worked.

Comment: just an fyi I am running 64 bit fedora 19 and as root i went to /etc/ssl/certs and saw there was a makefile so I ran it with a different serial i.e.: $ make SERIAL=5. tried git and it worked. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @BrandonDewey good catch! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 16):

This works for me

```
git config --global http.sslCAPath /etc/pki/tls/certs
git clone <repository>
```

Comment: Why the heck this is not included in the Github Quick setup page is beyond me - I'm sure everyone goes through this rigmarole to begin with !!

Answer (score 14):

This works for me

```
git config --global http.sslVerify "false"

git clone < repo-url >
```

Comment: I would not advice that: it would disable SSL check for *all* repositories. Yes, as a test just for *one* repository, you can do a `git -c http.sslVerify=false clone < repo-url >`. But for *all* repositories, it is best to resolve the root cause rather than circumventing the TLS security entirely.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a refresher here... I think the tip is msi here. Check your Git remote's origin: got that issue while being on a "https" origin (from cloning). Changed that to SSH protocol and it worked.

To check remote's origin:

```
git remote -v
```

To change remote's origin:

```
git remote set-url origin [repo-url]
```

Hope this helps anyone encountering the problem in the future.