# Unable to push on git. SSL certification verfication

Tags: git, ssl

I've been searching for a way to access or by pass the verification for github in order to push my files onto my existing repository. However, everytime I tried to do it, git always denied my access. I saw few older posts said you could turn the sslverify off but it did not work for me. Help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the message I got

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/C---programs-small.git/': SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
exeter {~/skyfire} > 
exeter {~/skyfire} > git config --global http.sslVerify false
exeter {~/skyfire} > git push origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/C---programs-small.git/': SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Comment: Disabling SSL certificate verification is ***extremely dangerous***. I don't know which "older posts" that you're referring to that recommends this, but they should all be downvoted. Disabling SSL verification would allow malicious people to tamper with the code that you're pulling and pushing to GitHub over HTTPS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL certificate rejected trying to access GitHub over HTTPS behind firewall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777075/ssl-certificate-rejected-trying-to-access-github-over-https-behind-firewall)

Comment: Also, you have the option of using git with SSH instead of over HTTPS/SSL if you want.