# SourceTree and Stash: Unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: git, ssl-certificate, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

We have Atlassian Stash installed on a Windows 2008R2 server, and for the most part everything is working nicely. We have an SSL certificate issued by our local on-premise CA and a DNS entry set up so we can go to `https://stash/` and it works quite nicely, except in Firefox where it throws a warning (related?).

When using Atlassian's Sourcetree we can navigate and choose a repository, but when we try to clone it we get the following error:

> fatal: unable to access `https://user@url/scm/etc/etc.git`: SSL
>   certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I get the same error if I try if from the git bash as well. Based on this error, I've tried [following the instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exe-s-store.aspx) on adding the SSL certificate to the Git as [also found on their website](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/SOURCETREEKB/Resolving+SSL+Self-Signed+Certificate+Errors), including what is in the comments, to no avail. I have exported the cert through Firefox and through the MMC certificate snap-in, gotten the same results and put it in its own file, combined with the curl file, and no matter what keep getting this error. I have yet to try getting it to work with SSH keys yet since I was hoping to make this easier for my team.

I also tried using [ssh myserver](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/260358/clone-failes-with-unable-to-access-url-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) and accepting the connection, and I entered my password and restarted; still the same error.

I do not want to simply [ignore certificate validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454754/792032) either, since that seems a bit pointless, then.

How can I get this working with our CA-issued cert?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After working with a peer who had been out until today, the revelation is that I had been using ONLY the certificate for the server itself. My [faulty] understanding of all the articles was that, similar to handling self-signed certs, you just tell Git to trust this cert. This is not the case for us.

Instead, it is the Root CA Cert from our domain that I should have been exporting and telling Git to trust. I swear I tried that early last week when this all first started, but to my shame I must not have.

Let this be a warning for anyone else who find themselves in my position!

Comment: can someone point me to a link showing how to do this?  I tried following the instructions here without any luck: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/

Comment: same question as @jessieloo: "how do you teach git to trust the Root CA Cert of the (local) bitbucket domain?" - would you mind to elaborate on that squid808?

Comment: Sorry @vrms - this was ages ago at a different job. IIRC, I followed the same instructions but with the root CA cert. I hope that helps you get close enough!

Answer (score 91):

I just disabled SSL certificate checks (which is fine for internal repos):

```
Sourcetree >
  Preferences >
    Git >
      Disable SSL certificate validation (ticked)
```

[image]

Comment: This defeats the purpose of SSL and exposes you to man in the middle attack.

Comment: @Stoyan as I said, for internal traffic, this is fine. If you have an internal man in the middle attack, you've got muuuch bigger problems than someone sniffing your code commits. If you're contributing remotely, then there is a risk, which might not be a big deal for example if it's open source anyway - what is the worst that can happen? They put some junk in your commit, whose later pull request is denied. Meh.

Comment: is there a way to Disable SSL certificate just to one repo? (i.e. I want this validation for all the rest of the repos I'm handling, except one)

Comment: @MichalTsadok I don't think so. It's a system-side setting

Comment: While this is great as a workaround it does not actually answer the question which states the OP does not wish to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the full chain certificate for your service which means not only your certificate but the intermidate and root ca in the cert file