# Webstorm unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, webstorm

When I try to checkout from a local Github then I get a SSL certificate error "fatal: unable to access ... SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate". However the server's certificate is known to Webstorm (9.0.0). I also checked the "automatically accept certificates" box.

How can I analyze / fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now I found out that this is not a Webstorm issue at all. Git did not want to checkout from the commandline either. I followed the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777075/ssl-certificate-rejected-trying-to-access-github-over-https-behind-firewall/4454754#4454754). Once Git was able to clone Webstorm was also able to clone. Obviously this is because Webstorm reuses the git configuration.