# Unable to pull/push in git repository

Tags: git, github-for-windows

```
$ git pull origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx': 
      error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/usr/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
```

I am getting this error when I pull or push my code.

Please guide me to fix this.

Comment: does the C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/usr/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt file exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github: error cloning my private repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778042/github-error-cloning-my-private-repository)

Comment: @Anthony - No, I just checked it its not there.. Thanks for quick reply

Comment: @Arvind_Kapse no problem ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was also facing this problem in windows and running git using gitbash. I just reinstalled gitbash, And gitbash automatically managed git certificate and its path needed.

Comment: Seems legit. This solution worked in my case. This happened to me after messing around with Git-via-SSH stuff.

Comment: How do you install gitbash alone?

Comment: @gath I am also looking for same.

Answer (score 48):

When using `https` you will need to supply password or using a certificate.
In your case looks like the certificate is not a valid one.

Try fixing it like this by telling git where to find the certificate:

```
// Add the certificate to your configuration file
git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

---

Alternatively, you could disable SSL checks:

```
// or switch off SSL checks completely by executing:
git config --system http.sslverify false
```

Set this in your config to disable it only for the given url and not for all requests

```
[http "https://weak.example.com"]
    sslVerify = false
```

---

#### `http.sslVerify`

> Whether to verify the SSL certificate when fetching or pushing over HTTPS.

---

#### `http.sslCAInfo`

> File containing the certificates to verify the peer with when fetching or pushing over HTTPS

Comment: it's not recommended to disable `sslVerify`

Comment: Agree, you can also disable it per url for a specific url as well

Comment: Would be much clever solution ^^, i didn't knew that, thanks @codeWizard

Comment: For anyone coming to this post, you don't need to disable https checks if you can provide git with a correct certificate.  Simply running the first command to point to the ca-bundle.crt file should be enough to resolve the issue.  If not, then try disabling SSL checks. :)

Comment: I used this for git version 2.12.2.windows.1:  `git config --system http.sslcainfo "c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt"`

Comment: I am running the following: error: could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Invalid argument
PS D:\angular-pwa-seed> git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
error: could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied
error: could not lock config file C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Invalid argument. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @Mark Are you using Git 2.16.2? I was having similar issues. Could not set ssl certificate location or disable ssl verify. I switched to Git 2.13 and ssl certificates work fine.

Answer (score 27):

I once had the same problem. My problem occured after re-installing git for windows. I'm using git for windows 64-bit on windows 10.

I found out that the installer did not install git anymore in `C:/Users/[USER_NAME]/AppData/Local/Programs/Git`. Instead it installed it under
`C:\Program Files\Git`.

Nevertheless the old config file `C:\ProgramData\Git\config` was not edited by the installer. This file still contains the old path so I edited it manually.

E.g. on my system I used

```
[http]
     sslCAInfo = C:/Programme/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

maybe you will have to use `Program Files` instead

```
     sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

**EDIT**

Like [DS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328565/ds) said in his comment

> C:\ProgramData\Git\config needs to be edited **as Administrator**.

E.g. right click on notepad and select ["Run as Administrator"](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/run-programs-administrator-ctrl-shift/) then open the file.

Comment: On systems with another locale, use this:
[http]
     sslCAInfo = C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\ssl\\certs\\ca-bundle.crt

Comment: Exactly what happened to me. One more note: C:\ProgramData\Git\config needs to be edited as Administrator.

Comment: Similar issue for me in Windows 10. "npm install" is not reading the same config file "git" does, seems like it is using the C:\ProgramData\Git\config location. So had to modify that file to add this to it (the workaround solution)
[http]
 sslVerify = false

Answer (score 14):

In version 2.x of git-bash The path to the .crt has changed to  ../Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt.  I had to update this manually in git-bash with

```
 git config --global http.sslcainfo "/path/to/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
```

Comment: Fixed it for me. I did VS2019 updates (LiveShare & Azure Data Lakes), then this broke but maybe coincidence, can't prove it was that. For reference this was my error:
Pushing feature/test
Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access 'https://mydomain.visualstudio.com/myproject/_git/myrepo/': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

or

Switch off your SSL by running this command

```
git config --system http.sslverify false
```

Comment: it's not recommended to disable `sslVerify`

Comment: Yes i agree. Its temp solution @AnthonyRaymond for debugging :)

Answer (score 5):

This issue might occur when git client is not able to find trusted CA for ssl. If you are in windows, try reinstalling it from https://gitforwindows.org/.

During the installation, select "Use the native Windows Secure Channel library" option.
That option will allow you to use your company's internal Root CA certificate instead of default ca-bundle.crt

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
 git config --global http.sslverify "false"
```

- will solve the problem
     after that Pop-up window appear to enter your username and password 
     make sure valid .

Answer (score 2):

If your git version is 2.8.1.windows.1,this may help you.
First , you need to locate your git home directory,mine is D:\SDK\Git.Just in the same directory,you can find folder "usr",open it and goes to \ssl\certs,you can find the certificate:ca-bundle.crt.

Then open console,execute:
`git config --system http.sslcainfo "D:\SDK\Git\usr\ssl\certscabundle.crt"`

Answer (score 2):

**This will do the work while moving from GIT 2.x clients to 2.5.x:**

Looks like after installing a new version of GIT client, it changes the path it looks for certificates from something like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64
```

to something like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec
```

To fix this, just copy the 'ssl' folder to the new location and it'll work like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Go your git directory and move the mingw64/ssl folder to mingw64/libexec/ssl

Comment: the answer is the best for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem after installing devel packages on cygwin.

I tried all of the fixes in this thread but nothing was working.

Then, I ran into [this thread on github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1484)

I found where CAPATH was being specified in gitconfig, and I deleted that https specification, and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is a lot of blind-leading-the-blind answers.
I'm just one more blind man here, but I just had the same issue and solved it by following [this easy article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590439/how-to-add-an-enterprise-certificate-authority-ca-to-git-on-cygwin-and-some-l). As I understand the original question, git is trying to find an SSL cert file in order to use the HTTPS protocol, and failing to find the file. Most of the answers here seem to focus on "well, just disable SSL then," rather than replacing the file correctly.

This incantation should generate the cert file and put it in the correct location for git on cygwin:

```
$ curl -sL http://ca.pdinc.us > /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ca.pdinc.us.pem \
&& update-ca-trust
```

In case you monkeyed with your git config (like I did) and need to set it BACK, this should do it:

```
$ git config --global http.sslcainfo "/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt"
```

One other side note which could be impacting many of the people reading this thread: The expected location of the cert file depends on which git executable you're running. Since we're talking about Cygwin, some (most?) of us probably have a Windows-native flavor of git installed too. If your Cygwin paths are set up to find the Windows git executable, your mileage may vary in terms of where to point the `http.sslcainfo` configuration. To check which executable is getting picked up for you:

```
$ which git
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem after my latest update of cygwin after installing Windows 10.
The command `update-ca-trust` failed during installation.

The reason seem to be that the group owner for the certificate folder was corrupt.
The somewhat drastic solution was to delete `/etc/group`, it turned out that cygwin is able to ask windows directly about group rights.

Solution found at http://zaunerc.blogspot.se/2016/01/cygwin-mapping-windows-sids-to-posix.html

Comment: I wanted to keep /etc/passwd since I use a different cygwin user name compared to windows. The workaround was to temporary rename /etc/passwd and restart cygwin (X server).

Answer (score 1):

I found the ssl certificate at :

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_[portable code]\usr\ssl\certs
```

then you can follow solution by [CodeWizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755598/codewizard) i.e. :

```
// Add the certificate to your configuration file
git config --system http.sslcainfo "[LOCATION_SPECIFIED_ABOVE]/cabundle.crt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Current Git for Windows build (2.18.0.windows.1) has a bug -- if the http.sslcainfo is not set it expects to find the certificate store in `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`.

Certificate store is actually installed to `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` so to fix that you must specify the proper path.

Furthermore, the SCHANNEL implementation is also broken in this build.

Finally, Git credential manager is also broken because if you have CI/CO credentials stored from gitlab-runner installation it will fail to clone/push/pull with access denied error instead of prompting for different credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I had previously installed git, then uninstalled it.

So for me was as simple as **reinstalling the correct version of git** (for me win x64) from

https://git-scm.com/download/win

Answer (score 0):

Using Intellij and git-sdk-64, and picked `git-sdk-64\mingw64\bin\git.exe` at first to be getting this issue, then when switched to `git-sdk-64\cmd\git.exe` it figured the cert file location alone and no other configuration was needed.  (have not used `git config --global http.sslcainfo ...`)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following steps useful in fixing the issue at my end for Windows 10:

Doing an uninstall of git.

However, git uninstaller doesn't do a clean job. So you may need to go delete the Git directory at C:\Users[My name]\AppData\Local\Programs\

After this, a fresh install of git should install install it in the C:\Program Files\Git directory where the config file points to in order to read the ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I fixed it reinstalling git in the default path:

C:\Program Files\Git

That's all

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error message but in my case it was because I've changed github settings to use ssh instead of https.

And the repository with the problem was cloned with https after removing the remote and re-adding it with ssh it's working as expected.

```
$git remote remove origin
$git remote add origin git@github.com:UserName/repo.git
```

Then `git remote show origin` is correctly showing the remote.

Comment: This answer ACTUALLY helped and SHOULD be the accepted answer. Its a MUCH simpler and SAFER sequence of steps that ACTUALLY WORKS.

DO NOT disable SSL via `git config --system http.sslverify false` because SSL is the encryption software which keeps your connection and your code secure in transit. Use the answer above my comment for REAL HELP.

Answer (score 0):

*I got the same error in Windows 7. Found that the certificate path referred in the error was not existing. Instead of ...\mingw32\usr\ssl... the cert file was in ...\mingw2\ssl... 
So I created  a usr folder manually and moved the entire ssl tree into usr. This fixed the issue.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1484
`git config --global http.sslverify "false"` will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error message but while cloning a github repository, unfortunately setting the `http.sslcainfo` didnt quite help. As I happened to be behind a corporate proxy server, setting the `http.proxy` fixed it for me.