# Linux Git: Unable to access remote: error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: linux, git

So I'm running OpenSUSE Leap 42.1, and Git 2.6.6. Up until today, I've had no problems pushing/pulling/fetching from a remote GitHub repo.

Now, today, I'm having this error message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myName/myProject.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
```

Anytime I do a push/pull/fetch, I get this. My first thought was to check that filepath that's provided, and no file named ca-certificates.crt exists in /etc/ssl/certs.

So... I'm not entirely sure what to do. Not sure why this suddenly stopped working either, maybe an OS or git update broke it? Either way, looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe github changed something. Does `git -c http.sslVerify=false fetch` works ?

Comment: Yeah that does work. I don't want to completely disable ssl though.

Comment: It seems to be a problem about github and its self signed certificate. Try to search about that on internet or SO

Comment: Just try to reinstall git as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510018/unable-to-pull-push-in-git-repository

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, sometimes the cert files change so you need to keep a bundle of several , rather that just one! Moreover, I will recommend to try and maintain the secure connection rather that turning it off with:

```
git config --system http.sslVerify false
```

Or worse:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

That is a very bad practice and should be avoided at all causes.

So first, look up that bundle cert file. In Windows, it is located under the git installation dir, something like:

[D:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt](http://D:%5CProgram%20Files%5CGit%5Cmingw64%5Cssl%5Ccerts%5Cca-bundle.cr)

In Linux, you can try something like this (I haven't try this though):

```
$ curl-config --ca
**/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt**
```

or maybe this other location:

```
**/etc/ca-certificates/extracted/ca-bundle.trust.crt**
```

Regardless where it maybe or the OS you are using once you get that bundle certification file, you then need to tell git to configure using that cert. You can modify the git.config file several why but one straight way is:

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

I hope it helps. For more information there is this other [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778042/github-error-cloning-my-private-repository). Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

check there may be a ssl file in somewhere else. I have the same problem in windows 10 installation and i solved it by making a usr directory and copy the content of ssl directory into usr directory.

Answer (score 0):

> Regardless where it maybe or the OS you are using once you get that bundle certification file, you then need to tell git to configure using that cert. You can modify the git.config file several why but one straight way is:
>
> ```
> git config --system http.sslcainfo /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
> ```

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), that would be:

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo %(prefix)/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

The pathname expansion (like "`~username/`") learned a way to specify a **location relative to Git installation** (e.g. its `$sharedir` which is `$(prefix)/share`), with "`%(prefix)`".

See [commit 7ed37eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ed37eb8ae485ff5590c656e871d6c739edfa067) (26 Jul 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit e394a16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e394a16023cbb62784e380f70ad8a833fb960d68), [commit a03b097](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a03b097d6307763c6778f5a1f194fbcbd158a5f7), [commit 644e6b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/644e6b2c0f55fa52de88586d375e03ac7f7914b7), [commit 789f6f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/789f6f226b6c7a5b28468044c1705c62aef5eeb9), [commit b7d11a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7d11a0f5d2db1eff623150cdc2a2ddccd6845b3) (24 Jul 2021) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit aab0eea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aab0eeaba56e87f4d471b8e2aba9a648e5606d01), 24 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`interpolate_path()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e394a16023cbb62784e380f70ad8a833fb960d68): allow specifying paths relative to the runtime prefix
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> Ever since Git learned to detect its install location at runtime, there was the slightly awkward problem that it was impossible to specify paths relative to said location.
>
> For example, if a version of Git was shipped with custom SSL certificates to use, there was no portable way to specify `http.sslCAInfo`.
>
> In Git for Windows, the problem was "solved" for years by interpreting paths starting with a slash as relative to the runtime prefix.
>
> However, this is not correct: such paths *are* legal on Windows, and they are interpreted as absolute paths in the same drive as the current directory.
>
> After a lengthy discussion, and an even lengthier time to mull over the problem and its best solution, and then more discussions, we eventually decided to introduce support for the magic sequence `%(prefix)/`.
>
> If a path starts with this, the remainder is interpreted as relative to the detected (runtime) prefix.
> If built without runtime prefix support, Git will simply interpolate the compiled-in prefix.
>
> If a user *wants* to specify a path starting with the magic sequence, they can prefix the magic sequence with `./` and voilà, the path won't be expanded.

`config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e394a16023cbb62784e380f70ad8a833fb960d68/Documentation/config.txt#L301-L309):

> If a path starts with `%(prefix)/`, the remainder is interpreted as a
> path relative to Git's "runtime prefix", i.e. relative to the location
> where Git itself was installed.
>
> For example, `%(prefix)/bin/` refers to
> the directory in which the Git executable itself lives.
>
> If Git was compiled without runtime prefix support, the compiled-in prefix will be substituted instead.
>
> In the unlikely event that a literal path needs to
> be specified that should *not* be expanded, it needs to be prefixed by
> `./`, like so: `./%(prefix)/bin`.