# Intellij IDEA: Repository test failed unable to access: error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018, intellij-idea2017

I have new empty public project in GitHub and i can't clone it. I installed new IntelliJ 2018 version and there's no `GitHub` option in `File->New->Project From Version Control`. So i've chosen `Git` option and added URL but it throws `Repository test failed unable to access: error setting certificate verify locations` error when i press `Test` button. The thing is i have IntelliJ 2017 in my second notebook and there IS `GitHub` option in `File->New->Project From Version Control` and i could clone the project there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message usually comes with a path pointing to the outdated certificate bundle file ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34510018/6309)).

Try and install the latest Git, and relaunch IntelliJ.

That or use the [SSH URL of your GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612800/6309) as a workaround.

Comment: Yes. It helped. Thanks!

Comment: @MukhamedaliZhadigerov What did you use? SSH URL? Or a new Git? What OS are you using?

Comment: new Git.And i'm using Windows 10. Actually i already had the lattest version so i uninstalled and downloaded the same version again. One more thing is: initially i downloaded git to C:/Program Files/Git. But then i moved it to C:/Git/. Maybe IntelliJ is indexing location of Git or smth (but of cource i changed location of git.exe in IntelliJ properties after i move). But this time i downloaded Git straight to C:/Git/ and now everything works fine.

Comment: @MukhamedaliZhadigerov Well done! Referencing explicitly your version of Git is a good idea. But do you see a GitHub option now?

Comment: No, GitHub option is still not there. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1

Comment: @MukhamedaliZhadigerov OK, maybe a plugin issue.