# boot2docker under proxy returns Forbidden

Tags: proxy, docker, boot2docker

Absolutely newer in docker, I just downloaded and installed the boot2docker for windows, set the proxy (and NO_PROXY) settings in my /var/lib/boot2docker/profile file once the vm is loaded, and restarted the VM.

The problem is I am getting a forbidden error when trying to search for / pull an image:

```
    docker@boot2docker:~$ docker search ubuntu
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/search?q=ubuntu: Forbidden
```

Another sample:

```
 docker@boot2docker:~$ docker pull hello-world
Pulling repository hello-world
FATA[0000] Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: Forbidden
```

Any clue?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807139/boot2docker-under-proxy-returns-forbidden

Comment: The provided link is for my question :o(

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy & paste fail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571070/how-to-ignore-certificate-errors-in-boot2docker-on-windows

Comment: Thanks for the input Doguhan, still the other question was not resolved, and yet I think the error is not related (mine is for access given by proxy, the other seems a certificate validation error, althought it uses a proxy).