# Disable registry update in Cargo

Tags: rust-cargo

How do I disable `cargo update` or `cargo build` from attempting to access github.com; but still download the appropriate package from `crates.io`

I have a single dependency in my cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
chrono = "0.2.14"
```

Running `cargo build`

```
E:\>cargo build
    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
Unable to update registry https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
```

We are **blocked** from github.com at work but not crates.io. Is there an option where cargo can still download the packages it needs without needing to update it's registry?

Comment: "*blocked from github.com at work*". That's really depressing.

Comment: What is the nature of the block? DNS, IP?

Comment: Both. I need git to be able to download the crates.io-index! I'll have to do it at home and send it to myself

Comment: @Ronnie: I’m failing to come up with an explanation as to why they would block github.com. Why do they?

Comment: Because someone uploaded some proprietary software once. So they blocked the complete site for all 100,000+ employees. We now read documentation on our mobile phones.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [configuring Cargo](http://doc.crates.io/config.html), you'll note there is an `index` key in the `[registry]` section.  This can be any path to a Git repository.

As such, you can make a local clone of the crates.io index.  I verified this by cloning it like so:

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index.git
```

then editing my Cargo configuration (specifically, I changed `~/.cargo/config`, but this should work anywhere the documentation describes) to contain:

```
[registry]
index = "file:///F:/Data/Repositories/crates.io-index.git"
```

A few things to note:

1. This *does not* mirror the actual contents of the packages.  Those come from a different host.  I do not know how to mirror those, however: Cargo is much better about caching those locally.  It *should* be enough to `cargo fetch` packages, then copy the cached `*.crate` files in `$HOME/.cargo/registry/cache/*`.
2. This causes the package identifiers in your `Cargo.lock` file to change.  This isn't a problem for developing libraries, but it *does* become a problem for *binaries*.  Standard practice is to check your `Cargo.lock` into source control for binaries so that everyone downstream builds with the exact same package versions.  However, the modified index means no one else will be able to build the package with that lock file in place.

   I've worked around this by placing *another* config override within binary packages that resets the index to the "official" one, but that may not even be possible in your situation.  In that case, you may need to either exclude `Cargo.lock` from source control, or just have a "doesn't use the official index" branch.

Comment: Or if you can access GitHub by IP address, maybe you can change it to `https://192.30.252.131/rust-lang/crates.io-index.git`. You’ll need `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true` in your environment, however, and that’s a bad idea. Alternatively, something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/3777141/497043.

Comment: the `registry.index` config value is no longer supported

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, cargo support `--offline` and [config](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netoffline) with `net.offline` only.
This flag add in [this PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/6934).

Answer (score 0):

Since the registry.index config value is no longer supported,
I could replace official crates.io registry use adding this
.cargo/config file in my project
(or under $CARGO_HOME%\.cargo) :

```
[source]

[source.mirror]
registry = "http://localhost:8185/auser/crates.io-index.git"

[source.crates-io]
replace-with = "mirror"
```

Also works using a file based git registry clone:

```
registry = "file://c:/github/crates.io-index.git"
```

downloaded either using git clone --bare or --mirror

cargo build now print
`Updating 'c:\github\crates.io-index.git' index`
instead of `Updating crates.io index`