# How to setup a local repository of 'crates.io'?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Visiting 'crates.io' is really slow in my country. Can I setup a local repository of 'crates.io' for our team? Is there any detailed documentation?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Disable registry update in Cargo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31029095/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster I think you're right... I was just writing up how to do this.  Do you know, I *completely forgot* that I'd already answered this?  Where would we be without you? :)

Comment: @DK.<3 Just doing my part to help out. :-)